# Spring 3.2.*, Error resolving placeholder with multiple <context:property-placeholder>

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

Sombody knows if this is a bug or an expected behaviour

If you have a component with

```
@Value("${foo}")
private String fooValue;
```

And this config:

```
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mortar" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:a.properties"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:b.properties"/>
</bean>
```

You get an Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo' in string value "${foo}"
```

If you use a singe context:property-placeholder it works just fine:

```
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mortar" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:a.properties, classpath:b.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:a.properties"/>
```

registers a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean and a bean of an inner class of this called `PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver`. Each of these beans registers a `PropertySource` in the Spring `Environment`.

Spring, when it has to resolve a `String` placeholder `${}` value then iterates through the registered `PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver` beans. It uses their `resolveStringValue` method to resolve the placeholder. If it cannot, it fails fast, even if another `PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver` could have resolved it.

The solution is to use a single `<context:property-placeholder>` where all the properties are registered in one `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Alternatively, you could declare them with the attribute `ignore-unresolvable="true"`. In this case, if one can't resolve it, it won't throw any exceptions. Instead it will try the next one. However, you might find yourself with an unresolved property, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi That's why I'm here :)